# Delete files on a SMB3 share to recycle bin

Tags: windows-10, smb, nas, synology

I have a Synology NAS (DS1621+) in my local network. A shared folder XXX is crated with SMB3 and SMB2 MTU enabled. The "Enable Recycle Bin" option is also activated for this shared folder. And I can see there is a #recycle directory in this folder.

In my Windows10 Pro, I connect to my NAS by using "Map network drive" in Explorer. But when I try to delete something in this shared folder, it always makes a "delete permanent", and the recycle option is in gray (see image below).

[image: Cannot choose "Recyle" option]

I've learned that SMB protocol supports truly the recycling functionality. So how could I fix this problem?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

After searching in a Chinese forum, I find out that this is just a graphical misunderstanding. In fact, the file is NOT permanently deleted when "Enable Recycle Bin" is activated on NAS. It will be moved to #recycle directory on your shared folder, and you can access it through Synology DSM. So, you can delete any files in Windows on that SMB share without any worries about permanent lost. But in Windows, it always shows a warning panel of "permanent delete" when you do a removing action.

If you want to deactivate the warning panel of permanent delete in your Windows, you can go to your user foled in C:\Users\{username}, choose a system default folder, for example "Downloads". Right click on this folder, go to "Location" tab and change the location to your SMB share. In this case, the files you that you delete will be showed in Recycle Bin on your Windows desktop as usual.

**References**

[简化操作：Win10删除群晖NAS文件不再显示【删除对话框】，Del即删除](https://post.smzdm.com/p/awx4zo9m/)

Answer (score 0):

From a windows point of view, every delete on a network share in permanent (not in windows recycle bin). It can't know that the NAS will do the move to its own recycle folder.